# How to pull Respiratory Rate data from the Google Fit REST API

Tags: c#, rest, google-fit

I am using the Google Fit REST API and want to get the respiratory rate. In the Google Fit app on Android, there is option to add Respiratory Rate. The API that I am using to fetch the data is:

```
GET /fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/{dataSourceId}/datasets/{datasetId}
```

and I am using dataSourceId for respiratory rate is derived:com.google.respiratory.rate:com.google.android.gms:merged but found blank array in my response like this -

```
{
  "minStartTimeNs": "1675209600000000000", 
  "maxEndTimeNs": "1675728000000000000", 
  "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.respiratory.rate:com.google.android.gms:merged", 
  "point": []
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Respiratory rate API is not documented elsewhere. Though, you may try the Health Connect API, it supports the RespiratoryRateRecord data type

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/health/connect/client/records/package-summary